# Is this positive term series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

My series is:

$\frac{1}{1+2^{-1}}\ +\frac{1}{1+2^{-2}}\ +\ldots$

I see my $nth$ term is $\frac{1}{1+2^{-n}}$

How do I test for its convergence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A necessary condition for the convergence of $\sum_n a_n$ is that $\lim_n a_n=0$. In your case, $\lim_n a_n=1$ so the series doesn't converge. In fact you can show that it diverges to $+\infty$ (every term in your sequence is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 2):

Since $2^{-n} < 1$, we have: $\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-n}} > \dfrac{1}{2}$, and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2}$ diverges to $\infty$. Using comparison test, we conclude that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1+2^{-n}}$ diverges.

Answer (score -3):

Yes the series convergent to 1.
Series 1/2 power n divergent but 1/2 power n converges to infinity and 1/1+2 power n converges to 1.